# What is currently a good approach to input masks when using Django model forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to find out what the best current approach is for input masks in Django when using model forms.

I have tried:
https://dobsondev.com/2017/04/14/using-jquery-mask-to-mask-form-input/

and

https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-number

but both approaches require that I catch the postback and remove the masking to prevent the model form validation from failing.

I can't help but wonder if there is a more eloquent approach/plugin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.